# Modal PopUp Button Works Only One Time

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-modal

I have a webform project that includes bootsrap Modal Popup with using Jquery.When  click on the button,my modal popup works but when i close the modal popup and click again on the button,it doesnt work.It works only one time.What is my mistake?I have added my code below.Please help me about my problem.

Thanks in advance.

**My Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_SifreDegistir").click(function(event) {
    $('#passwordModal').modal('show');
  });
  $('#passwordModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h5>Merhaba
        <asp:Label ID="lblKullaniciAdi" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" /> </h5>
      <h5>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="pull-right" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click" Font-Underline="True">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
      </h5>
      <h1>Raporlar</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
      <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
      </asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="btn_SifreDegistir" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="btn_SifreDegistir_Click" Text="Şifre Değiştir" />
          <p />
        </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:updatepanel>
      <div class="modal fade" runat="server" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" id="passwordModal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Şifre Değiştirme</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;width:340px">
                    <label for="inputPassword">Şifreniz</label>
                    <input class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Şuanki Şifreniz" type="password" id="inputPassword" style="width:100%;" />
                  </div>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblSifre" runat="server" style="color:red;display:inline-block;" Text="Merhaba" />
                  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;width:340px">
                    <label for="inputNewPassword">Yeni Şifreniz</label>
                    <input class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Yeni Şifreniz" type="password" id="inputNewPassword" style="width:100%;" />
                  </div>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblYeniSifre" runat="server" style="color:red;display:inline-block;" />
                  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;width:340px">
                    <label for="inputNewPasswordControl">Yeni Şifreniz Tekrar</label>
                    <input class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Yeni Şifreniz Tekrar" type="password" id="inputNewPasswordControl" style="width:100%;" />
                  </div>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblYeniSifreKontrol" runat="server" style="color:red;display:inline-block;" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <asp:Button ID="btn_PasswordChange" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="btn_PasswordCange_Click" Text="Değiştir" />
                  <asp:Button ID="btn_PasswordClose" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" Text="Kapat" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this `$(this).empty();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_SifreDegistir").click(function(event) {
    $('#passwordModal').modal('show');
  });
  $('#passwordModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    //$(this).empty();
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h5>Merhaba
        <asp:Label ID="lblKullaniciAdi" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" /> </h5>
      <h5>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="pull-right" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click" Font-Underline="True">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
      </h5>
      <h1>Raporlar</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
      <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
      </asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="btn_SifreDegistir" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="btn_SifreDegistir_Click" Text="Şifre Değiştir" />
          <p />
        </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:updatepanel>
      <div class="modal fade" runat="server" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" id="passwordModal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Şifre Değiştirme</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;width:340px">
                    <label for="inputPassword">Şifreniz</label>
                    <input class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Şuanki Şifreniz" type="password" id="inputPassword" style="width:100%;" />
                  </div>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblSifre" runat="server" style="color:red;display:inline-block;" Text="Merhaba" />
                  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;width:340px">
                    <label for="inputNewPassword">Yeni Şifreniz</label>
                    <input class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Yeni Şifreniz" type="password" id="inputNewPassword" style="width:100%;" />
                  </div>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblYeniSifre" runat="server" style="color:red;display:inline-block;" />
                  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;width:340px">
                    <label for="inputNewPasswordControl">Yeni Şifreniz Tekrar</label>
                    <input class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Yeni Şifreniz Tekrar" type="password" id="inputNewPasswordControl" style="width:100%;" />
                  </div>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblYeniSifreKontrol" runat="server" style="color:red;display:inline-block;" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <asp:Button ID="btn_PasswordChange" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="btn_PasswordCange_Click" Text="Değiştir" />
                  <asp:Button ID="btn_PasswordClose" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" Text="Kapat" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is work

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

try attribute

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal
```

**add**

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Modal Example</h2>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <form name="test">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <input type="text"/>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').find('form')[0].reset();
})
</script>
```

Add a script tag at the end

Comment: Thank you,it works but when i open again,the previous data is still there,the modal doesnt refresh and empty the form controls.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the Modal the same way you show it (click on Close button):

```
  $('#btn_PasswordClose').on('click', function() {
     $('#passwordModal').modal('hide');
     $('.passes').val('');
  });
```

You can empty your password fields by adding class e.g., "passes" to them and emptying their values as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net MVC use partial view  for modal content (modal head and modal body),once you hit the button it will move to your previously created partial view (on that paste modal code). Link for modal content: "https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp"

1) Add this to Your first page content

```
<div class="modal fade" id="previewApplicationForm1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function previewPopUpForApplicationForm1() {
    $("#previewApplicationForm1").load('@Url.Action("PopUpForPreviewApplication1","Registration")',
        function () {
            $("#previewApplicationForm1").modal("show");
        });
```

Once you hit the Submit Button it will redirect to Popup page.